# Comando "kotlinc" no sirve al momento de compilar script de Kotlin en el CMD de Windows

Tags: java, kotlin

Acabo de empezar a aprender Kotlin. Mi idea es comenzar realizando programas con el "Standalone Compiler" que me proporcionan en la página oficial de Kotlin.

Yo poseo una máquina con Sistema Operativo Windows, para lo cual necesité descargar la versión que se encuentra en este repositorio: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.20

El archivo que descargué fue "experimental-kotlin-compiler-windows-x64.zip". Después de descomprimirlo agregué la carpeta bin que se encontraba dentro de él a mis variables de entorno. Cabe señalar que el JDK de Java ya está agregado a mis variables de entorno, tengo la versión 1.8.0_111.

Al reiniciar el CMD y escribir el comando 'kotlin -version' me aparece lo siguiente: Kotlin version 1.3.20-release-116 (JRE 1.8.0_111-b14). Lo cual quiere decir que el compilador de Kotlin si se configuró correctamente como variable de entorno, al parecer.

El problema surge al momento de ejecutar el comando "kotlinc" dicho comando me permite compilar archivos de Kotlin para poder correrlos en el CMD.

Así que, al momento de crear un programa sencillo como el siguiente:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
    println("How're you?")
}
```

Guardarlo con el nombre "hello.kt" y compilarlo con el siguiente comando:

```
kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu.trove.THashMap
>           at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.CharsetToolkit.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.intellij.util.LineSeparator.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.intellij.util.LineSeparator.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.intellij.util.LineSeparator.getSystemLineSeparator(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.PlainTextMessageRenderer.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.MessageRenderer.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.trove.THashMap
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 11 more

De la misma manera, se supone que si quiero ejecutar el shell de Kotlin, sólo tengo que ingresar el comando "kotlinc" sin ningún argumento posterior, para poder inicializarlo, pero me aparece el mismo error.

¿Alquien sabe a qué se debe?

Comment: Tal vez tenga que ver con la ubicación de tu JAVA_HOME , KOTLIN_HOME o CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Ya revisé tu código, hay un error en el main. Te falta especificar que Array es de tipo String. Intenta compilar y ejecutar de esta forma:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
println("Hello World!") 
println("How're you?") 
}
```

**Compilar:** kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar

**Ejecutar:** java -jar hello.jar

Si no funciona, puede ser que no tengas bien especificadas tus variables de entorno.